# Node JS res.send not a function

Tags: node.js

i'm trying create first node js api.

i wroted this code but when i start server.js it's not working.

here code :

```
    var  executeQuery = function(res, query){             
     sql.connect(dbConfig, function (err) {
         if (err) {   
                     console.log("Error while connecting database :- " + err);
                     res.send(err);
                  }
                  else {
                         // create Request object
                         var request = new sql.Request();
                         // query to the database
                         request.query(query, function (err, res) {
                           if (err) {
                                      console.log("Error while querying database :- " + err);
                                      res.send(err);
                                     }
                                     else {
                                       res.send(res);
                                            }
                               });
                       }
      });           
}
```

when i start it error say :

C:\node\atlasErpApi\server.js:47  res.send(res);
TypeError: res.send is not a function at C:\node\atlasErpApi\server.js:47:43

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring a new variable `res` as argument to your `request.query` callback which shadows the `res` the comes as argument to your `executeQuery` function.

This should be most obvious at the line `res.send(res)` which, if you think about it, doesn't make sense at all.

Use different variable names for the two. For example, change the inner one to `sqlRes`:

```js
var executeQuery = function(res, query) {
    sql.connect(dbConfig, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error while connecting database :- " + err);
            res.send(err);
        } else {
            // create Request object
            var request = new sql.Request();
            // query to the database
            request.query(query, function(err, sqlRes) { // <<< CHANGED to sqlRes
                if (err) {
                    console.log("Error while querying database :- " + err);
                    res.send(err);
                } else {
                    res.send(sqlRes); // This makes more sense now :-)
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Note: Technically this also happens for `err` - you have an `err` from `request.query`'s callback shadowing the `err` from `sql.connect`'s callback. But this usually doesn't matter because you won't need to use the outer `err` in the inner callback.